# Argument of type 'typeof Row' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent

Tags: visual-studio-code, svelte

I'm using Svelte in combination with a component library named svelte-materialify. For all the components of this library VSCode gives me the following error message when I import one of the components into my pages, e.g. when I import the 'Row' component:

```
Argument of type 'typeof Row' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent'.
Types of construct signatures are incompatible.

Type 'new (props: RowProps & { children?: any; class?: string; } & Record<string, any>) => Row' is not assignable to type
     'new (args: { target: any; props?: any; }) => ATypedSvelteComponent'.

Type 'SvelteComponent<RowProps>' is missing the following properties from type 'ATypedSvelteComponent': $$events_def, $$slot_def
Possible causes:
- You use the instance type of a component where you should use the constructor type
- Type definitions are missing for this Svelte Component. If you are using Svelte 3.31+, use SvelteComponentTyped to add a definition:
  import type { SvelteComponentTyped } from "svelte";
```

The applications compiles and runs fine without any error messages in the browser. I have no clue what this error tries to tell me and how I can fix it. I would be very thankful if somebody could point me into the right direction.

Comment: You probably should not be using `svelte-materialify`, the project has been archived.

Comment: That's true, but for now I stuck with it cause replacing it is not a trivial task. Since it is open source I got the source code, and if something in that library is causing this error then I would try to fix the library, but as far as I can see it there seems to be nothing wrong with the type definitions of the library.

Comment: Hello there, I am having the same issue, `is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConstructorOfATypedSvelteComponent'.` - only in VScode, like you the browser works fine. I'll let you know if I fix it.